# Executing cmd script remotely on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, remote-desktop, script

I am using [Airytec Switch Off](http://www.airytec.com/en/) which creates a server on Windows that accepts commands on a specified network port and executes scripts remotely. Turning off/restarting PC works fine.

Then I created a custom `cmd` script, say `open_matlab.cmd` which simply has the word `matlab` as a command. When I execute it locally it works and Matlab opens. But when I run it remotely via Airytec a process is created in Task Manager but Matlab is not opening. The same happens with `Open calculator.cmd` which is preinstalled in Airytec directory i.e. it creates a process but it's not opening calculator. All custom scripts are located in `C:\Program Files\Airytec\Switch Off\scripts` and the system is Windows 8.1 x64.

I have also tried different commands such as `start matlab.exe`,

`C:
cd Desktop
start matlab.exe`

that all work locally but not remotely. Is there any security setting I have to change?

Comment: Hi, are you able to open any graphic program with this kind of script? Is it possible with  Airytec Switch Off maybe you need a remote desktop like program. BTW why the bash tag?

Comment: Ok from [this page](http://www.airytec.com/en/switch-off/feature.aspx?id=predefined-scripts) it seems you can. Did you open something _predefined_ and graphic? If you are able to do it, you can exclude problem with graphic connections and you can take inspiration from there.

Comment: @Hastur From those predefined scripts actually only calculator is preinstalled. Either way, I was not able to make any script to open a program graphically. They only work locally. I have also tried with Skype but same thing. It just opens a process, CPU usage goes up and then drops to around 1%.

Comment: Just an idea: check if you have some firewall that inhibit the graphic traffic (port, services... ) on both computer, and try again with the calc script. From the previous link it seems you can make start Ms Word too give it a try to that one too...  but better to do test on calc. (the simpler the better).

Comment: @Hastur I don't know which ports/services refer to graphic traffic in order to forward or enable them. Are you referring to the graphics card driver?

Comment: Maybe you can find interesting this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol). Usually RDP connections  are through TCP and UDP 3389. I don't know (if and if yes) which one will be used by _ Airytec Switch Off_. If there is some action made by the firewall you should see it in its log. I'm sorry but I cannot help you more than this. Good Luck. ps> try to ask to the software  producers. If you want to run _heavy_ programs I suppose it is better to run a remote desktop session.

Comment: Hey, i ran into the exact same problem. Airytec's web interface can only execute the shutdown/sleep/restart commands. Calc and any other predefined scripts i make do run the process but nothing happens. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @krasatos Hi. At that point I was just trying to execute Matlab scripts on my PC from the Android Matlab client. I have no follow-up updates so far. I am just using Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx). It's a sysinternals (now Microsoft) product and works nice and easy; just run the exe with remote computer name and location of the executable (or script) you want to start. 
It's easy scriptable too!